# Access first to GRUB in dual boot with WINDOWS 8

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

I've already install a dual-boot verison of ubuntu on my windows 8.

When I launch my computer, I don't see the grub, it launch windows 8.

During the launch of the computer I can press 'esc' so I get on the windows 8 interface for boot selection and I can select 'ubuntu' and then I see the grub and I can choose ubuntu.

So it works, BUT it's a long way to simply boot on my ubuntu partition.

My question is, how to automatically start on the grub and not on windows 8.

Thanks,

Comment: Is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair of any help?

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to first see GRUB, I believe you want to change the default operating system in the Windows 8 partition, as outlined [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-default-operating-system-for-startup-multiboot).

Basically you can modify which operating system will boot first by changing the default OS in `Startup and Recovery` in `Advanced System Settings` in `Control Panel`.

If you boot to the Linux partition first, you will see GRUB.